# Twilio -3rd party Sip VOIP - CLI configuration

Tags: php, command-line-interface, twilio, sip, voip

I'm trying to generate calls using:

1. Twilio voice api
2. VOIP provider with CLI access (SIP)

The provider requires that we send the destination number with a prefix of 1234 followed by 00 and the mobile number.

This is the code I'm using the below,

```
    $client = new Client($sid, $token);
    $call = $client->calls->create(
    "sip:123400XXXXXXXXX@YY.ZZZ.YY.ZZZ", "+XXXXXXX",
    array("url" => "http://url.com/hello.xml")
    );
```

When i run the script, it gives me instance or call ID and everything as if the call is sent, I go to the account check the logs and it gives failed without any error code.

We're using a simple XML below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Response>
    <Say>Hello</Say>
</Response>
```

Is there any recommendations / best practices i should be aware of?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here exactly. Why send a real number through a VOIP provider when you can accomplish calls from just Twilio? Can you give a bit more context? Also, what does the [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/debugger) say?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is that my solution requires international CLI feature which Twilio cannot support/guarantee [link](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132227-Local-Caller-ID-CLI-international-compatibility), so I thought of using Twilio API to accomplish what we need since I don't have time to create or learn a software for that purpose. The debugger is not showing anything, although the calls are shown in the logs of the interface as failed. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Ok, I see. Was there anything in the debugger?

Comment: No, the debugger shows nothing. is there anything in the code I should add to enable debugging?

Comment: Hmm... no, you shouldn't need to add anything. I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) to see if they can dig in and see why you don't get a more useful error.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I will drop them an email. But as far as you know, are we able to accomplish calls through Twilio API the way I'm trying to?

Comment: Actually, what TwiML are you using for the URL you supply to that call?

Comment: A local file we have on our servers that has the following xml 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say>Hello</Say>
</Response>

Comment: I'd update the question if you're going to add XML :)

Comment: I might have an idea actually! Answer coming up.

Comment: Actually, I don't. [The docs say you should be able to make a SIP call in this format](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls). Your call would only say "Hello" to the person answering the SIP phone. I recommend getting in touch with support to let them know and find out about why you're not getting a good error code from the failed call.

Comment: Exactly that's the part of the docs I was reading all along... couldn't get my hands on what I might be doing wrong. I'll take this to support as you suggested. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries, sorry I couldn't be of more help.